# Calculate/validate bz2 (bzip2) CRC32 in Python

Tags: python, c, crc, crc32, bzip2

I'm trying to calculate/validate the CRC32 checksums for compressed bzip2 archives.

```
.magic:16                       = 'BZ' signature/magic number
.version:8                      = 'h' for Bzip2 ('H'uffman coding)
.hundred_k_blocksize:8          = '1'..'9' block-size 100 kB-900 kB

.compressed_magic:48            = 0x314159265359 (BCD (pi))
.crc:32                         = checksum for this block
...
... 
.eos_magic:48                   = 0x177245385090 (BCD sqrt(pi))
.crc:32                         = checksum for whole stream
.padding:0..7                   = align to whole byte
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2

So I know where the CRC checksums are in a bz2 file, but how would I go about validating them. What chunks should I `binascii.crc32()` to get both CRCs? I've tried calculating the CRC of various chunks, byte-by-byte, but have not managed to get a match.

Thank you. I'll be looking into the bzip2 sources and `bz2` Python library code, to maybe find something, especially in the `decompress()` method.

**Update 1:**

The block headers are identified by the following tags as far as I can see. *But tiny bz2 files do not contain the ENDMARK ones.* (Thanks to **adw**, we've found out that one should look for bit shifted values of the ENDMARK, since the compressed data is not padded to bytes.)

```
#define BLOCK_HEADER_HI  0x00003141UL
#define BLOCK_HEADER_LO  0x59265359UL

#define BLOCK_ENDMARK_HI 0x00001772UL
#define BLOCK_ENDMARK_LO 0x45385090UL
```

This is from the `bzlib2recover.c` source, blocks seem to start always at bit 80, right before the CRC checksum, which should be omitted from the CRC calculation, as one can't CRC its own CRC to be the same CRC (you get my point).

```
searching for block boundaries ...
block 1 runs from 80 to 1182
```

Looking into the code that calculates this.

**Update 2:**

`bzlib2recover.c` does not have the CRC calculating functions, it just copies the CRC from the damaged files. However, I did manage to replicate the block calculator functionality in Python, to mark out the starting and ending bits of each block in a `bz2` compressed file. Back on track, I have found that `compress.c` refers to some of the definitions in `bzlib_private.h`.

```
#define BZ_INITIALISE_CRC(crcVar) crcVar = 0xffffffffL;
#define BZ_FINALISE_CRC(crcVar) crcVar = ~(crcVar);
#define BZ_UPDATE_CRC(crcVar,cha)              \
{                                              \
   crcVar = (crcVar << 8) ^                    \
            BZ2_crc32Table[(crcVar >> 24) ^    \
                           ((UChar)cha)];      \
}
```

These definitions are accessed by `bzlib.c` as well, `s->blockCRC` is initialized and updated in `bzlib.c` and finalized in `compress.c`. There's more than 2000 lines of C code, which will take some time to look through and figure out what goes in and what does not. I'm adding the `C` tag to the question as well.

By the way, here are the C sources for bzip2 http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz

**Update 3:**

Turns out `bzlib2` block CRC32 is calculated using the following algorithm:

`dataIn` is the data to be encoded.

```
crcVar = 0xffffffff # Init
    for cha in list(dataIn):
        crcVar = crcVar & 0xffffffff # Unsigned
        crcVar = ((crcVar << 8) ^ (BZ2_crc32Table[(crcVar >> 24) ^ (ord(cha))]))

    return hex(~crcVar & 0xffffffff)[2:-1].upper()
```

Where BZ2_crc32Table is defined in `crctable.c`

For `dataIn = "justatest"` the CRC returned is `7948C8CB`, having compressed a textfile with that data, the crc:32 checksum inside the bz2 file is `79 48 c8 cb` which is a match.

**Conclusion:**

bzlib2 CRC32 is (quoting `crctable.c`)

> Vaguely derived from code by Rob
>   Warnock, in Section 51 of the
>   comp.compression FAQ...

...thus, as far as I understand, cannot be precalculated/validated using standard CRC32 checksum calculators, but rather require the `bz2lib` implementation (lines 155-172 in `bzlib_private.h`).

Comment: `bzip2` uses the AUTODIN-II, Ethernet & FDDI 32-bit CRC standard

Comment: Doesn't the CRC refer to the uncompressed data that this block contains?

Comment: The first thing that I had tried was calculate the CRC for the plain, uncompressed data. But it won't match. The data was a simple `hello` in a text file. I tried different CRC32 calculators online and library ones that I have at my disposal. Either I'm very unlucky, or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `open("test.txt.bz2","wb").write(bz2.compress("hello"))` CRC32 tag states that the CRC32 for the block is `19 31 65 3d`, whereas `hex(crc32("hello"))` (from `binascii`) returns `36 10 a6 86`

Comment: I suppose the CRC32 is the CRC32 of the compressed blocks

Comment: "But tiny bz2 files do not contain the ENDMARK ones." -- They do; blocks aren't padded to bytes, so you'll also have to look for bitshifted versions of the magic values.

Comment: @Soulseekah Since you've edited your title to include '[SOLVED]' can you post an answer with your conclusions and (optionally) mark it as the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is the CRC algorithm used by `bzip2`, written in Python:

```
crcVar = 0xffffffff # Init
    for cha in list(dataIn):
        crcVar = crcVar & 0xffffffff # Unsigned
        crcVar = ((crcVar << 8) ^ (BZ2_crc32Table[(crcVar >> 24) ^ (ord(cha))]))

    return hex(~crcVar & 0xffffffff)[2:-1].upper()
```

(C code definitions can be found on lines 155-172 in `bzlib_private.h`)

`BZ2_crc32Table` array/list can be found in `crctable.c` from the `bzip2` source code. This CRC checksum algorithm is, quoting: *"..vaguely derived from code by Rob Warnock, in Section 51 of the comp.compression FAQ..."* (`crctable.c`)

The checksums are calculated over the **uncompressed data**.

Sources can be downloaded here: http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz

Comment: Here's the bzlib2 CRC implementation in Java http://www.zetagrid.net/zeta/doc/src/org/apache/tools/bzip2/CRC.java.html

Answer (score 0):

To add onto the existing answer, there is a final checksum at the end of the stream (The one after `eos_magic`) It functions as a checksum for all the individual Huffman block checksums. It is initialized to zero. It is updated every time you have finished validating an existing Huffman block checksum. To update it, do as follows:

```
crc: u32 = # latest validated Huffman block CRC
ccrc: u32 = # current combined checksum

ccrc = (ccrc << 1) | (ccrc >> 31);
ccrc ^= crc;
```

In the end, validate the value of `ccrc` against the 32-bit unsigned value you read from the compressed file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the fastcrc python library which have bzip2 crc32 implementation.

https://fastcrc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fastcrc.crc32.bzip2