# What is a ethernet frame sample which can be sent?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, crc32, raw-ethernet

i want to send a ethernet frame from FPGA to my PC for wireshark to receive

i pass payload into CRC generator to get the CRC result, but i guess CRC error as wireshark not received any thing which is my payload

i got 2 ideas

```
1. find a ethernet frame in hex code in internet and copy to VHDL to send in order to make sure no CRC error and check whether it send or not? could you post a correct ethernet frame in hex code here?

1b. any free CRC generator code in VHDL available in internet? and any free CRC generator code in C++ language or C# language or Java language for hard code CRC in ethernet frame?

2. use layer 2 programming in ubuntu to send a ethernet frame to another computer,
whether i can send and display the ethernet frame which i send in ubuntu or i need to capture with wireshark in another computer?
```

Comment: If all you need is an ethernet frame, why not use Wireshark to capture packets from you browsing to this website?

Comment: The answer to this question may be helpful, although I don't think it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497608/calculate-and-validate-ethernet-fcs-crc32-in-vhdl

Answer (score 0):

Use your FPGA tools to create an Ethernet core.  This will usually create a testbench for you too.  Run that testbench, note down the values of the data produced.

As another alternative, there are some Python libraries I've used in the past to create Ethernet packets.

http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/source/browse/trunk/dpkt/ethernet.py

I've never used this, but it looks like it might be helpful:

http://packeth.sourceforge.net/packeth/Home.html