# check FCS ethernet frame CRC-32 online tools

Tags: frame, ethernet, crc

I'm trying to check the FCS of an ethernet frame thanks to tools on different website.

I first used this website:
http://depa.usst.edu.cn/chenjq/www2/software/crc/CRC_Javascript/CRCcalculation.htm and find the next FCS : 0xD4C3C62F (the frame below)

Then, I tried this one : http://www.scadacore.com/field-applications/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/ and I found the correct CRC : 0x7AD56BB3 but nothing of the different kind of CRC-32 (normal, reversed...) correspond to the CRC find on the first website.

Is there any link between algorithms?

Thank you!

Here is the hexadecimal frame (no start of frame) :
000AE6F005A3001234567890080045000030B3FE0000801172BA0A0000030A00000204000400001C894D000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F10111213

Answer (score 3):

Beware of online CRC calculators.

The Ethernet CRC of your string is actually `0xb36bd57a`. It is stored in reverse order in the stream, which is why you wrote it incorrectly as 0x7AD56BB3.

There are many CRC definitions, including many 32-bit CRC definitions. See the [RevEng catalog](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/) for examples. The one you want happens to be called ["CRC-32", with this definition](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/17plus.htm#crc.cat-bits.32).

The "CCITT-32" (a name I have not seen before) being calculated in your first link is some other definition. It does not even appear in the RevEng catalog.

Comment: That's why you said "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497608/calculate-and-validate-ethernet-fcs-crc32-in-vhdl" on the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497608/calculate-and-validate-ethernet-fcs-crc32-in-vhdl query!

Answer (score 2):

A more descriptive and clear update to @Mark Adler's answer (I am new here so I can't edit or comment)

The CRC you are searching for is called [**CRC-32/ISO-HDLC**](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/17plus.htm#crc.cat-bits.32/).
You can check the following online calculator and check the one named "CRC-32":
https://crccalc.com/

Each CRC32 algorithm has its own [parameters](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/crc/introduction.html#crc.introduction.intro_crcs.intro_crcs_rmca) for its generation, like polynomial, init,...etc
The IEEE802.3 standard defined the CRC32 algorithm parameters for the FCS field to have the polynomial(0x04c11db7), init/xorIn(0xffffffff), xorout(0xffffffff)