# Variable length messages in Verilog (serial CRC-32)

Tags: verilog, crc32

I'm working with a serial protocol. Messages are of variable length that is known in advance. On both transmission and reception sides, I have the message saved to a shift register that is as long as the longest possible message.
I need to calculate CRC32 of these registers, the same as for Ethernet, as fast as possible. Since messages are variable length (anything from 12 to 64 bits), I chose serial implementation that should run already in parallel with reception/transmission of the message.

I ran into a problem with organization of data before calculation. As specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047494/python-crc-32-woes) , the data needs to be bit-reversed, padded with 32 zeros and complemented before calculation.

Even if I forget the part about running in parallel with receiving or transmitting data, how can I effectively get only my relevant message from max-length register so that I can pad it before calculation? I know that ideas like

```
newregister[31:0] <= oldregister[X:0]    // X is my variable length
```

don't work. It's also impossible to have the generate for loop clause that I use to bit-reverse the old vector run variable number of times. I could use a counter to serially move data to desired length, but I cannot afford to lose this much time.

Alternatively, is there an operation that would directly give me the padded and complemented result? I do not even have an idea how to start developing such an idea.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood how to do a serial CRC; the Python question you quote isn't relevant. You only need a 32-bit shift register, with appropriate feedback taps. You'll get a million hits if you do a Google search for "serial crc" or "ethernet crc". There's at least one Xilinx app note that does the whole thing for you. You'll need to be careful to preload the 32-bit register with the correct value, and whether or not you invert the 32-bit data on completion.

*EDIT*

The first hit on 'xilinx serial crc' is xapp209, which has the basic answer in fig 1. On top of this, you need the taps, the preload value, whether or not to invert the answer, and the value to check against on reception. I'm sure they used to do all this in another app note, but I can't find it at the moment. The basic references are the Ethernet 802.3 spec (3.2.8 Frame check Sequence field, which was p27 in the original book), and the V42 spec (8.1.1.6.2 32-bit frame check sequence, page 311 in the old CCITT Blue Book). Both give the taps. V42 requires a preload to all 1's, invert of completion, and gives the test value on reception. Warren has a (new) chapter in Hacker's Delight, which shows the taps graphically; see his website.

You only need the online generators to check your solution. Be careful, though: they will generally have different preload values, and may or may not invert the result, and may or may not be bit-reversed.

Comment: Care to elaborate or give me an example of those 'million hits'? I found some Xilinx app note, but it was out of date for our equipment and my superiors decided not to use it. I also found a number of calculators and code generators, but as far as I understood the latter, they only did the very CRC calculation, while I still needed to organize the data before and after it. It is true that I only tried them out on a different CRC calculation, not the here mentioned CRC-32, and since I needed additional work there, I expected it to be the same here.

Answer (score 0):

Since `X` is a viarable, you will need to bit assignments with a for-loop. The for-loop needs to be inside an always block and the for-loop must static unroll (ie the starting index, ending index, and step value must be constants).

```
for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1) begin
  if (i<X)
    newregister[i] <= oldregister[i]; 
  else
    newregister[i] <= 1'b0; // pad zeros
end
```

Comment: And everything needs to be wrapped in an always block to work?

Comment: Also, well, I tried this now on a different example, and it doesn't work. It looks like only the if part executed, but not else.

Comment: (A) Yes, it needs to been in an always block. (B) It should work, can you show more of your code. If `X` is also a register, then I would recommend moving logic calculations from the synchronous logic (ex. `always @(posedge clk)`) to combinational logic (e.g. `always @*`), keep the register assignment in the synchronous logic block.